# Allow users to edit account, without id being in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that in devise if you want to edit your account you can go to /registrations/edit to edit the account.

However I'm on a project where I'm just using omniauth. So I created a controller called

```
users_controller
```

that will allow the user to edit their account information etc. However if I do

```
edit_user_path
```

it want's me to give the id, how can I do this but still have a clean URL like devise does, where I don't have to make it users/:id/edit?

Answer (score 0):

In devise, you don't need the `id` because the `id` is calculated by the `current_user` which is stored in session.

So, if you want to edit your user's profile without an `id`, you must ensure the `id` could be found somewhere, via session/cookie.

```
# set into session
session[:user_id] = 3
# read from session
User.find session[:user_id]
```

refer to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: I store the id in a session, how would I approach doing this?